# How to return warnings from server side to silverlight

Tags: silverlight, warnings

We have a business case that need to return both validation errors and warings from server side and display on silverlight.
I see the silverlight is using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult to process errors. It does not contain and fields for "warnings".

I am wondering if anybody has a good idea to handle this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think ValidationResult is used by ValidationException which is thrown by the subclasses of ValidationAttribute. Normally this mecanism is used with blocking validation errors because throwing to exception stops execution of the code. If it happens in your service, the exception can be sent to the client and processessed, but this is not always a wanted scenario.

You could extend this model (those classes ValidationAttribute, its subclasses, ValidationException are not sealed) to add a warning flag but then you'd have to trap the exception to continue the processing and rethrow in case of a warning.

Another alternative is to add business logic validation errors and warnings to your response to the client. I like this approach because you can then include whatever info you want the way you want/need it.

Comment: Thanks. Currently my solution is to take any errors from server and add them into context.ValidationResults, so that ValidationSumarry can pick them up and display. However, ValidationResults is only for errors and doesn't have room for warnings... Do you think I should inherit MS' class and add my fields? Is it a good solution? Or is there anything better. I could not return validation errors for some technical reason...

Comment: ValidationResult is sealed unfortunately. If you don't show errors and warnings simulteanously, you could set a flag on your ViewModel to indicate whether you have errors or warnings and style the ValidationSummary accordingly. I'll look for a better solution and post back if I find something.

Comment: Check the remarks on the documentation for INotifyDataErrorInfo (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx) as I think it is a good starting point on customizing errors on your ViewModel. In this case however, you would implement the interface on your ViewModel to notify the ui that new errors are available, instead of adding the errors to the ValidationContext.

Comment: Another workaround would be to prefix your error messages with a letter, E for errors and W for warnings. You could then use the ValidationSummary.ErrorStyle property to define an inline style in which you would define a new template. In the template, you can use ValueConverters to set an image or color based on the first character of the error message (to indicate an error or warning) and another ValueConverter to strip the letter from the message to display it. This would allow you to keep using the silverlight validation engine and also give visual indication for warnings.